# Form submit with jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can someone help me with this problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/mgzea0uw/1/

I try to check all data before making a call to my server to save the information. Does someone have an idea why this form isn't hidding the message when nothing is entered inside it?

I got the idea that he won't run the jquery code.

I would like to safe the information this way after validation:

```
        var UrlToPass = 'title='+tit.val()+'mes='+mes.val();
        $.ajax({ 
        type : 'POST',
        data : UrlToPass,
        url  : '/publish.php',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
                window.location.replace("index.php");
        }
        });
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks in adventage!

Comment: what exactly do you expect to happen? and what of that doesn't?

Comment: I would like that if you click on safe and you enter nothing in message and title that both fields get hidden...

Comment: you missed an & character in the data string. better use: $form.serialize()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `event.preventDefault();` to stop browser from redirecting you along with request to another page when you click button. Also I changed `mes` to `tit` in first `if` construct.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#titel').focus();
    $('#opslaan').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var tit = $('#tit');
        var mes = $('#mes');
        if(tit.val() === ''){
            tit.addClass("hidden");            
        }
        if (mes.val() === '') {
            mes.addClass("hidden");
        }
    });

});
```

[Working demo.](https://jsfiddle.net/mgzea0uw/2/)